# Returning a value from a method from a loop

Tags: for-loop, return-value

I am having such a code as show below:

```
private static String getShoppingLine()
{
    for(int index = 0; index <= ProductInfoName.length; index++)
    {
           return ProductInfoName[index];
    }
}
```

But it states an error to have a return statement at the end. But I already had one in the loop. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String getShoppingLine()
{
    for(int index = 0; index <= ProductInfoName.length; index++)
    {
           return ProductInfoName[index];  // don't do this.
    }
    return null;  //add here too
}
```

Instead of writing `return` statement inside, `for-loop` write it outside. Because, control will return back at `ProductInfoName[0]`.

**NOTE :** Your `return` statement must be found within the method (if you have declared any return type to your method). Since, there is no guarantee that, your `for-loop` always execute. Then, in such case your method won't return anything. So, you need to add one more `return` statement outside your `for-loop`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does. `ProductInfoName.length` may be negative. If it's negative, your `return` statement won't be executed.

Note: of course in reality it can't be negative, but the compiler doesn't know that when compiling your code.

Second note: this isn't the way to write this method. You are always returning the first element in the array (and if it doesn't exist, you'll be throwing an exception). You should replace your code with:

```
private static ...
{
    if(ProductInfoName.length>0)
        return ProductInfoName[0];
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will always return ProductInfoName[0] , 
why dont you just write return productinfoname[0] ? 
and what if there is no object in the array at all ?

Answer (score 0):

you are not returning anything in your code.

if you want to return the last value change to like the code given below

```
private static String getShoppingLine()
{
    String str="";
    for(int index = 0; index <= ProductInfoName.length; index++)
    {
           str=ProductInfoName[index];
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: it will always return last element. :/

Comment: Dude, i didn't said anything. I just said, it will return always last value. That's it.